# How can I make a Python virtualenv meant for another platform?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm writing a program on a computer running Ubuntu with an x86-64 processor that needs to run on a computer running OS X with an x86 processor. I'm probably not going to be able to do any kind of library installation, so a venv is pretty much the only option I know of.

How can I make one targeted for that platform?

If I can't, is there a better way to ship the libraries with the program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Virtualenvs are **not** a packaging mechanism. There is no reason a virtualenv should ever leave the computer it was created on. It won't work, the virtualenv is 100% specific to your OS, CPU architecture, Python version, etc.

There are a number of solutions for packaging. The old and still current way is specifying dependencies in `setup.py`, and running `setup.py install` on the target machine. Note that this *can* happen inside a virtualenv, you just have to create the virtualenv and run setup.py in there. Both virtualenv and the standard library `venv` in 3.3 provide ways of doing this automatically after virtualenv creation.

If you absolutely must create a binary distribution (e.g. because you need an extension module and the end user doesn't have a compiler), you need an egg or a wheel or one of the .py-to-binary converters (py2exe, PyInstaller, cx_Freeze, etc.). You will need access to an OS X machine to create that. And at least the wheel and the egg are usually installed anyway, so using them doesn't save you any of this hassle. That's because they are formats for binary distribution, their primary purpose is pushing the **build** step from the end user to the developers, not to remove the installation step.

In summary: Just create a script which creates a virtualenv and installs your application as well as the required libraries.

Comment: Is there any way of creating a setup that I can just move to the target without any kind of installation on their end? All they already have is Python.

Comment: The .py-to-binary tools *may* be able to do that, and the result won't even need an existing Python installation. But as I said, you need access to the target OS to generate such a binary. A virtualenv-based solution doesn't need that and should work as well even though it technically "installs" something (but only to the virtualenv, not to system directories).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this as the python executable you use on Ubuntu is not going to run on OS X, even if the architecture is the same.

If you're trying to distribute a Python program without installation, you could look at something like [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/). You'll still need access to a machine running OS X to generate the app bundle, but you should be able to package up everything into a .app bundle that is launched like a standard OS X application.