# understanding virtual environment behavior when moving to a different machine

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, virtualenv

I moved the `venv1` virtual environment's **content** from a computer into  `venv2`, a virtual environment located in a different computer.

So, on the new computer, when I run `cd venv2` and then `source bin/activate` I noticed this weird behavior on Terminal:

```
(venv1) me@machine2:~/venv2
```

I would like to know if someone can explain me why I am not positioned into

`(venv2) me@machine2:~/venv2`

instead?

Comment: I'm pretty sure moving a venv to a different machine is not a supported operation. There are lots of ways you could just get a crash instead of any useful behavior.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Port Python virtualenv to another system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587840/port-python-virtualenv-to-another-system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `activate` script does this around line 43:

```
VIRTUAL_ENV="/full/path/to/venv1"
export VIRTUAL_ENV

_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH="$PATH"
PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
export PATH

# unset PYTHONHOME if set
if ! [ -z "${PYTHONHOME+_}" ] ; then
    _OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME="$PYTHONHOME"
    unset PYTHONHOME
fi

if [ -z "${VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT-}" ] ; then
    _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1="$PS1"
    if [ "x" != x ] ; then
        PS1="$PS1"
    else
        PS1="(`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`) $PS1"
    fi
    export PS1
fi
```

so it will still look (and show it in your prompt) for the original `venv1` directory. Unless your `machine2` has the same directory tree things will not work.