# PyCharm's venv relies on a physical python installation?

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv, python-venv

I trusted PyCharm to let it create a venv for me, and then shipped the code project with the venv folder. Inside my code, whenever calling a separate script, I use the venv Python uder `venv/Scripts/`.

To my surprise, it breaks when running on another machine, where the venv python actually points to my local installation of Python at `C:\Python\Python37`. This beats the purpose of creating a venv!

What have I done wrong? My project structure is like

- code/*.py
- venv

And this is what I shipped to another machine.

Comment: Virtualenvs are not portable! They're development tools but not distribution/deployment ones.

Answer (score 2):

Yes venv creates a link to your original python.
The best practice to creating "venv requirements" is to create requirements file:
`pip freeze > requirements.txt`
Then just add this file to your project folder

P.S
There is better alternative called [Conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/). You can provide the python version in conda envs.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @AndreyG's answer. In addition, a bunch of others similar questions were helpful, like:

[Copy complete virtualenv to another pc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34993200/copy-complete-virtualenv-to-another-pc/34993306#34993306)

[Port Python virtualenv to another system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587840/port-python-virtualenv-to-another-system/46802017#46802017)

Especially after reading this tutorial: https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/,

I realized my venv misconception, which was kinda due to my previous experience on shipping among Mac machines, where Python was usually preinstalled.

Now combined with the pip-freezing approach towards shipping `site-packages`, I also ship the Python Windows installer and automate the installation to make sure that the venv symlinks point to the exact same Python installation on all machines. Reference:

https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html

The automation code:

```
python.<version>-<arch>.exe /quiet InstallAllUser=-1 PrependPath=1 TargetDir="C:\Python\Python<version>"
```